# Ubuntu Linux server CIFS VFS error

Tags: server, cifs

The Ubuntu Linux server started reporting this to me:

`[1286554.137588] CIFS VFS: \\192.168.1.111 Send error in SessSetup = -11`

What's the mistake I should start looking for and fix?